# Can the word "crooning" be used as an adjective?

Tags: word-usage

I've looked up some dictionaries online, but they list "croon" as either a verb or a noun. Can "crooning" be used as an adjective?

For example, She sat listening to a soft, crooning song.

Comment: (Almost) all _ing_ forms of verbs can be used as an adjective, which is why dictionaries don't bother to mention it with every single verb.

Comment: Yes, as  oerkelens said.

You might just as easily find your example "She sat listening to a soft, crooning song" or "She sat listening to (someone) crooning a (soft) song…"

Comment: @oerkelens was doing to answer yes but could not find a single dictionary to cite such.

Comment: Singers croon, songs don't croon. To croon is to sing or hum in a low voice and in a sentimental way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes (and no).

The *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED) lists examples of *crooning* as an adjective as far back as 1599:

> Be cruining Bulls of heigh and haughtie minde.

*Cruining* is just an older, alternative spelling of *crooning*. There were many alternative spellings of words before dictionaries. That example is by Alexander Hugh from *Hymnes, or sacred songs*.

George Eliot wrote in *Adam Bede* in 1859

> The cocks and hens..made only crooning subdued noises.

The inimitable PG Wodehouse wrote in *Blandings Castle* (1935)

> Everybody knows what Crooning Tenors are... They sit at the piano and gaze into a girl's eyes and sing in a voice that sounds like gas escaping from a pipe about Love and the Moonlight and You.

But of course he is writing facetiously and often used modifiers in  ways such as using them before objects when describing the actor/subject: *he put the rueful kettle on the stove*, such that that which is *rueful* is the one who put the kettle on, not the kettle (which is an example I made up, but not unlike how Wodehouse used adjectives).

In short, yes you can say

> She sat listening to a soft, crooning song.

But, some readers may not think it a very good usage, if they think that it is not really the song that is crooning, but the singer of the song. So it may come across as having the same effect as that of a dangling or other misplaced modifier. If I were writing this sentence I might choose a different way to write it, so that it avoids the use of *crooning* as modifying *song*. To many, a song doesn't croon; a singer does.

Answer (score -2):

Your example is flawed in two ways. Croon; is "soft, low voice or tone" and related to being melodic and musical. So, *'soft, crooning song'* says the same thing, three times. It is redundant. **"She sat listening to the crooning wind move through the forest."** would work though.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if "crooning" could be used that way. Your example clearly means the wind was crooning or singing, so it would grammatically work either way. But I've been seeing some examples in Google Books that use "crooning" as an adjective before a noun like a "song." For example: a slow crooning song. I'm not familiar with this usage, so I asked.

Comment: @skywardhope English can be very tough. Some sentences that are expressively correct, are not grammatically correct. "Frank Sinatra was known as a *'crooner'*. The slow, low, moody feeling of his tempo and music gave crooning songs a standard bearer. " It works, but is not grammatically correct.

Comment: Redundancy is not ungrammatical.

Comment: This answer is right on. In any case, a person croons, ***a song does not croon***. That's the main point. I do not get these downvotes for the life of me.

Comment: There are soft songs and there are loud songs. *"Soft song"* is in no way redundant. Ditto for *crooning*.  *Croon* doesn't just mean to sing softly, no matter what the dictionary you got the definition out of says. [This dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/croon) defines it as *to sing or talk in a sweet, low voice full of emotion*. It's not redundant.

Comment: @Peter Shor I understand your objection, but maintain it is redundancy.  "She sang a soft 'lullaby' song." is also redundant. The 'soft' and 'lullaby' are stretching the dual usage - as there is no such thing as a harsh loud lullaby. (except a very old Punk Band). When you add 'song' to the mix, you are overboard (redundant) in your description. How is a lullaby not a song? How is a lull-aby not inclusive of a soft? In musical terminology, this is very redundant.

Comment: I didn't say that *"lullaby song"* wasn't redundant. Do you think *"crooning"* means *"lullaby"*?

Comment: They are both terms which are descriptive of musical styles. A lullaby is; soft, slow, and a song. To croon, crooning, is slow, melodic, moody ballad type of song. They describe music, and sound intensity. I used 'lullaby' as a variation on musical terms to point out the redundancy.

Comment: The questionable sentence above is; "She sat listening to a soft, crooning song." changing that to; "She sat listening to a soft, lullaby song." highlights the same redundancy of terms in describing the music.

Comment: The problem with *soft, crooning song* has nothing to do with redundancy. Would you say that *he crooned a lullaby* is redundant, and you should say *he crooned a song* or *he sang a lullaby*? The problem with *soft, crooning song* is that songs don't croon, singers do.

Comment: Ask a musician.

Comment: Better answer: ( I don't like being flippant), Croon, to croon, crooning can not be used to describe anything that is not related to a song or music. Poetry doesn't croon. Literature doesn't croon. 'All water is wet, but not all that is wet is water' logic doesn't apply here.